# Python Pandas spit to series groupBy

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which I can run split on a specific column and get a series - but how do I then add my other columns back into this dataframe? or do I somehow specify in the split that there's column a which is the groupBy then split on columnb ?

input:

```
ixd   _id     systemA         systemB
0   abc123  1703.0|1144.0   2172.0|735.0
```

output:
pandas series data (not expanded) for systemA and B split on '|' groupedBy _id

Comment: you should provide a minimal input/output example for clarity

Comment: added more detail

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a regular `.groupby` will achieve what you are after:

```py
for specific_value, subset_df in df.groupby(column_of_interest):
   ...
```

The `subset_df` will be a pandas dataframe containing only rows for which `column_of_interest` contains `specific_value`.

Comment: Thanks- added more details to the post but not sure if that even changes anything here

Comment: I'm not looking for specific value though? just a split on the two columns as mentioned in my OP

Comment: Also this doesn't help me add the new series back into the dataframe